# How to get the property of an array using filter

Tags: javascript, filter, geolocation

I'm trying to get the match from the following array comparing the coordinates from the browser vs the coordinates on the array, but I get an 'undefined' value when I call the const 'matchgeosucursal' even if I force the condition of the filter to match, the goal of this code is to get the URL of the matching scenario, I think I'm using the filter function wrong.

```
//Request permissions
$( document ).ready(function getLocation() {
  
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
      console.log ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

    
//Filter and gets match url

function showPosition(position) {  
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude)
  console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
  var navlat = position.coords.latitude; //Browser lat
  var navlon = position.coords.longitude; // Browser lon

  // Array
  var sucursales = [
    {lat: 21.924089, lon: -102.293378, url: "https://shorturl.at/test1"},
    {lat: 21.859964, lon: -102.298034, url: "https://shorturl.at/test2"},
    {lat: 32.45569, lon: -116.836181,  url: "https://shorturl.at/test3"},
    {lat: 24.114868, lon: -110.340389, url: "https://shorturl.at/test4"},
    {lat: 21.0335386, lon: -89.559187, url: "https://shorturl.at/test5"}];
  
//Match result
  const matchgeosucursal = sucursales.filter( sucursales =>  sucursales.lat === navlat && sucursales.lon === navlon);
  console.log('Match> ' + matchgeosucursal);

       
 }

});
```

Comment: What are the *actual* values of `navlat` and `navlon`?

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but what is the *actual* value (as in, what number) of those variables. If nothing matches the result *will* be an empty array.

Comment: Its variable, I'm using test values for privacy, it should be the lattitude(navlat) and longitud(navlon) requested by the browser, it should match the last scenario: lat: 21.0335386, lon: -89.559187.

Comment: [Works fine if I put sensible values](https://jsfiddle.net/51n6tcw9/).

Comment: Also, I guess you should *return* `matchgeosucursal` rather than just logging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine, the only thing is that `console.log` doesn't print objects properly. I used `console.table`  in my test and everything looks good:

Note: I made `position` a const because I can't pull the coordinates from a document like you have done. But it will work as long as it has correct values for `position.coords.latitude` and `...longitude`

```
const position = {
  coords: {
    latitude: 21.0335386,
    longitude: -89.559187,
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude)
  console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
  var navlat = position.coords.latitude; //Browser lat
  var navlon = position.coords.longitude; // Browser lon

  // Array
  var sucursales = [
    {lat: 21.924089, lon: -102.293378, url: "https://shorturl.at/test1"},
    {lat: 21.859964, lon: -102.298034, url: "https://shorturl.at/test2"},
    {lat: 32.45569, lon: -116.836181,  url: "https://shorturl.at/test3"},
    {lat: 24.114868, lon: -110.340389, url: "https://shorturl.at/test4"},
    {lat: 21.0335386, lon: -89.559187, url: "https://shorturl.at/test5"}];

//Match result
  const matchgeosucursal = sucursales.filter( sucursales =>  sucursales.lat === navlat && sucursales.lon === navlon);
  console.log("Match:")
  console.table( matchgeosucursal);


 }


showPosition(position)
```

Comment: Well, it's likely because you hard-coded the exact coordinates that are in your array `sucursales` in this example.  I would think you'd want to check if `position` was *close enough to* one of the sucursales instead of exactly equal.  [This page](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Decimal_degrees) has a handy chart that tells you the actual distance that a change of 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000 of a degree correspond to.  You might decide that if a person is within 100m of your lat/long coords, they are "in" the surcursal.

Comment: I only hardcoded the values that were given in the comments by original question owner. He didn't mention that he was looking to match within a range.

Comment: Sorry Anshu for some reason I thought it was your question.

Comment: No worries James!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are getting an undefined result because your filter is looking for an exact match for latitude and longitude, and the user's geolocation isn't accurate enough to pinpoint the exact latitude and longitude that you are filtering for.

To get a match, you could check if the user's latitude and longitude are within a range, like so:

```
const matchgeosucursal = sucursales.filter( sucursales =>
            sucursales.lat >= (navlat -.005) &&
            sucursales.lat <= (navlat +.005) &&
            sucursales.lon >= (navlon -.005) &&
            sucursales.lon <= (navlon +.005));
```

That would give you accuracy within about a half of a mile. Obviously, you can adjust how wide of a range you would like to use, as needed for your use case.

```js
//Request permissions
$( document ).ready(function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        console.log ("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }


//Filter and gets match url

    function showPosition(position) {
        console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude)
        console.log("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        var navlat = position.coords.latitude; //Browser lat
        var navlon = position.coords.longitude; // Browser lon

        // Array
        var sucursales = [
            {lat: 21.924089, lon: -102.293378, url: "https://shorturl.at/test1"},
            {lat: 21.859964, lon: -102.298034, url: "https://shorturl.at/test2"},
            {lat: 32.45569, lon: -116.836181,  url: "https://shorturl.at/test3"},
            {lat: 24.114868, lon: -110.340389, url: "https://shorturl.at/test4"},
            {lat: 21.0335386, lon: -89.559187, url: "https://shorturl.at/test5"}];

//Match result
        const matchgeosucursal = sucursales.filter( sucursales =>
            sucursales.lat >= (navlat -.005) &&
            sucursales.lat <= (navlat +.005) &&
            sucursales.lon >= (navlon -.005) &&
            sucursales.lon <= (navlon +.005));
        
        console.log('Match > \nlat: ' + matchgeosucursal[0].lat +"\nlon: " + matchgeosucursal[0].lon + "\nurl: " + matchgeosucursal[0].url);


    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```